# Alternative or Equivalent Product for GUI ScreenIO required for Microfocus Cobol

Tags: user-interface, microfocus

We are working on a project that involves the conversion of old DOS based screen panels to Windows based graphical user interface using GUI Screen IO.

We got in touch with the company recently to purchase the software but company is apparently in transition of selling and have discontinued the business of providing the licensed S/W. So, we are unable to get a licensed copy of this GUI ScreenIO s/w which would impact our project.

Q --    Has anyone ever heard of another presentation layer s/w that is very similar to GUI ScreenIO and can work with native Cobol? Please let us know.

Thanks,
Kishan

Comment: Please provide any suggestions or thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your info about the discontinuation of Gui ScreenIO comes a bit as a surprise to me.
I am a GuiScreenIO user myself and have heard nothing from the vendor about an end-of-life strategy, what so ever, and was billed for support just a few months ago! 
If what you state is true (and I have no reason to doubt your writing), I will have to look for an alternative myself as well.

There is an alternative product called SP2 (Flexus) that has an approach comparable to  GuiScreenIO. Since you are at the beginning of the character-based-to-windows-transition you might want to take a peek at it! ;)

Feel free to ask if you need more info about transitioning character based cobol applications to Windows.

Kind regards,
Paul